# Retrieve and Print XML Name Value pair in the Gridview or in a Textbox of a webform

Tags: asp.net, xml, c#-4.0

How do I retrieve the Name and Value field from below XML file and show it in the webform in a Gridview or in a Textbox.

'<'PublisherProperty'>''
    '<'Name'>'Channel'<'/Name'>'
    '<'Value'>'943'<'/Value'>'
    '<'PublisherID'>'PUBLISHER'<'/PublisherID'>'
  '<'/PublisherProperty'>'
  '<'PublisherProperty'>'
    '<'Name'>'Queue'<'/Name'>'
    '<'Value'>'q123'<'/Value'>'
    '<'PublisherID'>'PUBLISHER'<'/PublisherID'>'
  '<'/PublisherProperty'>'
  '<'PublisherProperty'>'
    '<'Name'>'QueueServer'<'/Name'>'
    '<'Value'>'U4VMMQSIT02'<'/Value'>'
    '<'PublisherID'>'PUBLISHER'<'/PublisherID'>'
  '<'/PublisherProperty'>'
  '<'PublisherProperty'>'
    '<'Name'>'QueueName'<'/Name'>'
    '<'Value'>'SIT'
    '<'PublisherID'>'PUBLISHER'<'/PublisherID'>'
  '<'/PublisherProperty'>'
  '<'PublisherProperty'>'
    '<'Name'>'QueuePort'<'/Name'>'
    '<'Value'>'2454'<'/Value'>'
    '<'PublisherID'>'PUBLISHER'<'/PublisherID'>'
  '<'/PublisherProperty'>'
  '<'PublisherProperty'>'
    '<'Name'>'QueueWaitInterval'<'/Name'>'
    '<'Value'>'-1'<'/Value'>'
    '<'PublisherID'>'PUBLISHER'<'/PublisherID'>'
  '<'/PublisherProperty'>'
  '<'PublisherProperty'>'
    '<'Name'>'Exception'
    '<'Value'>'9501'
    '<'PublisherID'>'PUBLISHER'<'/PublisherID'>'
  '<'/PublisherProperty'>'
  '<'PublisherProperty'>'
    '<'Name'>'ExceptionText'<'/Name'>'
    '<'Value'>' Error'<'/Value'>'
    '<'PublisherID'>'PUBLISHER '<'/PublisherID'>'
  '<'/PublisherProperty'>'
  '<'PublisherProperty'>'
    '<'Name'>'MsgElement'<'/Name'>'
    '<'Value'>'null'
    '<'PublisherID'>'PUBLISHER'<'/PublisherID'>'
  '<'/PublisherProperty'>'

Comment: Please provide XML Data

Answer (score 0):

To bind xml data with GridView, I suggest you to use **XmlDataSource** and modify your xml file a little bit.

This is modified sample xml file named **"XMLFile.xml"**, added `<data>` as root element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
  <PublisherProperty>
    <Name>Channel</Name>
    <Value>943</Value>
    <PublisherID>PUBLISHER</PublisherID>
  </PublisherProperty>
  <PublisherProperty>
    <Name>Queue</Name>
    <Value>q123</Value>
    <PublisherID>PUBLISHER</PublisherID>
  </PublisherProperty>
</data>
```

And this is aspx code to get the data

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="xmlDataSource" runat="server" DataFile="XMLFile.xml" XPath="data/PublisherProperty"></asp:XmlDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="xmlDataSource" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName" Text='<%# XPath("Name") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value">
            <ItemTemplate><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblValue" Text='<%# XPath("Value") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Note that you have to set a correct xml path such `XPath="data/PublisherProperty"` when you want to query against  element.